# Accessing Pages Views from Power BI Audit Logs using Dataflows

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm currently working on building **custom usage metrics reports** for Power BI and I'm facing an issue with accessing **Page Views data from the Power BI Audit Logs within Dataflows**.

***Here's the problem I'm encountering:*** I have access to the Power BI Dataflows Audit Logs, which provide me with information on workspaces, reports, datasets, gateways, etc. However, **I haven't been able to find the data related to Page Views within the data flow.** As I can see its possible via API but I need to access or view the data via dataflow.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could guide me on how to **retrieve** **the Page Views data from the Power BI Audit Logs using** **Dataflows**. Any suggestions, insights, or solutions would be highly valuable.

[image: Screenshot of Usage Metrics Report]

**Out IT team has created a custom dataflow exposing only the following attributes from the audit log :**

RecordType
CreationTime
Operation
OrganizationId
UserType
UserKey
Workload
UserId
ClientIP
UserAgent
Activity
ItemName
WorkSpaceName
DatasetName
ReportName
CapacityId
CapacityName
WorkspaceId
AppName
ObjectId
DatasetId
ReportId
IsSuccess
ReportType
AppReportId
DistributionMethod
ConsumptionMethod
TableName
DashboardName
DashboardId
Datasets
EmbedTokenId
CustomVisualAccessTokenResourceId
CustomVisualAccessTokenSiteUri
DataConnectivityMode